# TypeScript Types without importing classes?

Tags: class, typescript, types, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm about to try implementing some IoC/DI framework in our application (thinking of Inversify, if there are any other recommendations) but we still have the problem of having to include the files for their Types. How do we get around this? We're using the latest version of TypeScript (2.3 as of writing this).

We have a lot of imports for various types, for example:

```
// Components
import {GuideTime} from '../components/guide-time/guide-time.component';
import {GuideNetwork} from '../components/guide-network/guide-network.component';
import {GuideDetail} from '../components/guide-detail/guide-detail.component';
import {Player} from '../components/player/player.component';

// Services
import {Keys, KeyService} from '../core/services/key.service';
import {GuideService} from '../core/services/guide/guide.service';
import {afterCSSUpdate} from '../core/services/utility.service';
import {DataService} from '../core/services/data/data.service';
```

Or just to get the type of something:

```
import {ITitle} from '../../models/title.interface';
import {IGuide} from '../../models/guide.interface';
```

Is there a way to consolidate these (preferably automatically, or globally)? I realize I can probably make a mytypes.ts file somewhere and then just import and export all the types from our application so there's a single, central file to import, but that introduces other problems (and a lot of work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make all of these global you would need to import them all to a single interface, and then import that interface wherever you need access to every type. Something similar to

```
import * as mainInterface from 'MainInterface'
```

Additionally, you could try importing for side effects only (which would give you access to the types), although this is not recommended in practice.

From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use: `import "./my-module.js";`

**EDIT** Additionally, similar to the above single interface solution, you can put each of the types into the same namespace. You can [spread a namespace across multiple files using this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983209/using-namespace-spread-over-multiple-files-in-typescript), which means you can just wrap each type in a main namespace.

```
namespace MainNamespace {

    export class GuideTime {
        ...
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but TSLint and various things I've read online recommended away from using namespaces. I have no idea why, though. Could you explain?

Comment: @ChrisSimpson Did they recommend against namespaces in general? Or in particular for solving this problem? Not sure why they would argue against them. Does the namespace solution solve your problem?

Comment: TSLint doesn't like it, and many sources online (including the TypeScript handbook) say namespaces shouldn't be used in favor of modules. I know I can get around it anyway, but it seems like there ought to be another approach that doesn't use something that seems to have resistance.

Comment: From a quick search it looks like the reasoning against namespaces is because it can add an unnecessary access layer to your classes that modules don't. This seems like what you are trying to do though, as you want to be able to access all your classes from one main import so I think it's an alright solution.

Comment: I suppose another way to put the question is, since I plan to implement IoC/DI, still referencing the file for the type seems like it would still break the IoC principle; so how would I get around this (not having to explicitly import a type, and/or import a type without specifying a path to the class/interface's file)?

Comment: @ChrisSimpson You're trying to create a global scope. TypeScript files don't know about other files or classes without some reference, most commonly imports, but you can also use `/// reference path=file.ts` to have global scope across files without imports statements.